# Problem on changing my nested state React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a state in my app which is something like following:

```js
const [companyCategories, setCompanyCategories] = useState({ loading: true, categories: null });
```

I fetch my categories from an API and set my categories like below:

```js
  const fetchCategories = useCallback(() => {
    fetch(***link***)
      .then(res => {
        if (!res.ok) {
          throw new Error('Failed to fetch.');
        }
        return res.json()
      })
      .then(data => {
        setCompanyCategories({
          loading: false, categories: data.map((el, index) => {
            return {
              id: el.id,
              title: el.title,
              selected: false
            }
          })
        })
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });

  }, []);
```

and if I log my `companyCategories` after that:

```js
Object {
  "categories": Array [
    Object {
      "id": 7,
      "selected": false,
      "title": "Casual",
    },
    Object {
      "id": 8,
      "selected": false,
      "title": "Coffe Table",
    },
    Object {
      "id": 10,
      "selected": false,
      "title": "Dining Table",
    },
    Object {
      "id": 11,
      "selected": false,
      "title": "Workstation",
    },
  ],
  "loading": false,
}
```

and here's my problem : consider I show this categories as buttons to UI of the app and when user tap on each it changes by the color and I need to alter `selected` attribute of the category to `true` which by default all of them are false means that none selected.
for this I code like this:

```js
  const onRadioBtnClick = (item) => {
    let updatedState = companyCategories.categories.map((el) => {
      if (el.id == item.id) {
        return {
          ...el,
          loading: true,
          categories: {
            ...el.categories,
            selected: !el.selected
          }
        }
      }
      setCompanyCategories(updatedState)
    });
  };
```

and this doesn't work, updatedState is showing me `undefined`. how can I manipulate one property of my nested state?

Answer (score 1):

You placed `setCompanyCategories(updatedState)` at wrong line.

It should be

```
const onRadioBtnClick = (item) => {
  let updatedState = companyCategories.categories.map((el) => {
    if (el.id == item.id) {
      return {
        ...el,
        loading: true,
        categories: {
          ...el.categories,
          selected: !el.selected
        }
      }
    }
  });
  setCompanyCategories(updatedState);
};
```